# laravel eloquent insert toSQL

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to get the raw sql from a laravel insert statement without executing it:

```
$new->table($newTable)->insert($newRows)->toSql();
```

Unfortunately, the insert does get executed

Comment: I don't think this is possible as the query builder don't make the full query before executing. Untill then it's just query-building-pieces without your data. When it executes it put the pieces together and then insert your data.

Comment: @PeterBechP Works fine for select statements

Comment: Ooh. I didn't know. But I looked into the insert method, and I can see its that function that runs the query. And there is no parameter you can set to get around. You could make a hack and make your own method and then bypass the query-insert, but then, is that really something you want? What do you need this for?

Comment: I need to get the raw query to use it in a DB::statement as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622395/how-to-correctly-use-laravel-with-sql-server-instead-on-mysql

Comment: @Chris write the raw query. Laravel doesn't provide way to do what you're asking for

Comment: Also I came to think about. There is no way the it works fine with select. I runs the query, but you dont notice because, it just reads and not inserting stuff. Only if you dont use any parameters in that select. The parameters will only first get inserted into the statement after being runned by.